# how to build and image recognition app on Android

Tags: android, image-recognition

well I want to develop an app that captures through the camera a DVD cover and searches through it's stored info for a match on that image and then gathers all of the info for the movie from IMDB. I really have got no clue whatsoever on where to start. I started using Qualcomms AR framework for it's image recognition capabilities but the docs are awful and the forums are quite empty. I was hoping someone could steer me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Luck! The google goggles app is similar to what you want to try, apart from your only searching movie covers, and that has taken some extremely experienced engineers 3-5years of research to achieve, they do plan on opening up an API for it but who knows when!

Here is an open API for visual search (image recognition): http://developer.iqengines.com/

I havent tried it personally, but might be worth a try, if not just wait for the goggles API!

Comment: I actually got some luck with the Qualcomm framework. it is just that for every image I have got to register it on their website as a trackable. I'll look into the api you linked. Thanks!

Comment: Also, have you thought about just taking a picture of the barcode on the DVD, i'm sure you can search IMDB by barcode and it would be alot simpler!

Comment: ACtually that is a really smart alternative. No I hadn't thought about it. Thanks!

Comment: I've just implemented QR/barcode code recognition in my app, check out google zxing, its super quick and does any type of barcode! http://code.google.com/p/zxing/